# Next.js/Square API error: Fetch API cannot load. URL scheme "webpack-internal" is not supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, square

I'm having this error when trying to pull stock from Square API.

```
injectGlobalHook.js:1648 Fetch API cannot load webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js. URL scheme "webpack-internal" is not supported.
```

I'm converting my React.js project into Next.js, so I'm just trying to learn the differences between the two.

Initially, I pulled the data with a `proxy` in my `config` file to avoid a `CORS Error`, but knew that was just a workaround for the time being because I needed to hide the `API_KEY`.

Now I'm trying to call the API the right way in Next.js backend options with `getServerSideProps`

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const allStockObjects = await fetch(requests.fetchAllStock, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers,
  })
    .then((res) => res.json)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  return {
    props: {
      allStockObjects,
    },
  };
}
```

Here is my export, but I have the exact same export in a Component with a `POST` request done the same way to the same Square API and it works perfectly fine.

I also check my `APILogs` on my Square Dashboard and the request never makes it to the API at all.

Not much online on this error or Square API for that matter, so I hope someone could help.

Comment: Does `requests.fetchAllStock` contain the expected value?

Comment: in my case this was due to a syntax error that webpack couldn’t detect (it was a duplicated variable name). could you please provide more code? what do you pass in headers? what does requests.fetchAllStock return?

Comment: @juliomalves it just has the url link to that specific API

Comment: @juliomalves I found out that the error was due to me calling getStaticProps at the `_app.js` file(next.js blocks API calls at that level). I'm still having trouble spreading that data throughout my application though. because I need `allStock` within every page, just in case a user shares a specific page. 
At the moment I'm calling the `fetchAllStock` API on every page but I would like it to be called once at the highest level component.

Comment: @OsamaRashid this is the issue I'm facing^^^

Comment: You can use [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) in `_app` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves Yeah, sorry I replied to this message before I saw your comment on my other question! I appreciate it!

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Persistent navigation in a NextJs \_app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619238/persistent-navigation-in-a-nextjs-app/65628271#65628271)?

Comment: @juliomalves I just read your reply in that answer, and I'm now wondering if I should do that because my API headers will have my API key within it. You mentioned that once the user redirects to another page it will be client-side rendered, at this point would it expose my API key?

Comment: Yes, it would. You could use an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction#use-cases) where the request will be made against, and make the API request from there to hide the environment variable from the client-side.

Comment: @juliomalves ok great, I'll try that! Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is caused by React Devtoools, specifically the setting `Always parse hook names from source (may be slow)` — if you turn this off when not needed it will prevent the error.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get this setting working? I want to be able to see what hooks are being updated from the profiler but it only shows "Why did this render: hooks 1, 3 and 6 changed"

Comment: This is like the old joke where the man goes to a doctor and says "It hurts when I do this" and the doctor says "then don't do that."

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a similar issue. For reference I am taking Wes Bos's course on React/ GraphQL. To get past the issue I shut down the frontend and then deleted the .next folder. Then re-ran the frontend so a new .next folder gets generated. I also cleared the browser cache. After that the issue went away for me.

Comment: this only works because refreshing the page turns off "Parse hooks" in react developer tools. Once you attempt to use the feature again, you will still get the error.