# How to call API once in _app and pass the data to the necessary children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently converting my React.js project into Next.js.

I'm running into a few issues with props at the moment though.

Previously with React, I made API calls at `app.js` then passed it down into the `navbar` to be used in a search form.

With Next.js there's not really an option since API calls are blocked from the `_app.js` file. Which is where my `layout.js` (Nav/Footer).

**options I'm considering:**

1. change the convention of the `index.js` file to be like the `app.js` instead of the `home.js` page.
2. wrapping the layout on every page instead of wrapping `_app.js` and calling stock API on every page.

I feel like there's a better way to just call the API once and pass it to the necessary children. If someone can give me any recommendation on how to combat top-level sharing of props that would be great!

Comment: Try to create custom `_document` file, [read more here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Persistent navigation in a NextJs \_app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628271/1870780)? You can use [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) in your custom `_app` to make the API calls.

Comment: @juliomalves I appreciate that. I believe that is exactly what I need! Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider doing the following

1.If the props are needed pervasively in the app eg. theme or auth object, create a Context provider and wrap the _app.js component with it.

2.If the props are needed in only few components, find the closest common ancestor and make the fetch there like you would normally do in React. additionally, in Nextjs, you can use [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) to pre-render pages on every request

Comment: Yes, I needed them for my Layout.js as well as every page so I believe using context.Provider or the `getInitialProps` would work at the `_app.js` level.
Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but be warned that the official docs don't recommend `getInitialProps` at the _app.js unless you have a blocking data requirement for every page. Doing so will server-side render every page and you will the benefit of automatic static generation of non-data blocking pages eg About page, FaQ page etc